# Symfony 4 and Mercure with Docker - Couldn't connect to server

Tags: symfony, docker, docker-compose, symfony4, mercure

I'm trying to run Mercure on Symfony with a Docker image.

symfony/mercure version: "v0.2.0",

docker-compose.yaml configuration:

```
  mercure:
    container_name: mercure
    image: dunglas/mercure
    environment:
    - JWT_KEY=MySecret
    - DEMO=1
    - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS=1
    - PUBLISH_ALLOWED_ORIGINS=http://my_project.com:9090/hub
    - DEBUG=1
    - CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS=*
    ports:
    - "9090:80"
```

When I go to http://my_project.com:9090/ can see the workable Mercure Debugging Tools page. The Mercure is properly installed and running with a docker container.

Symfony .env file:

```
MERCURE_PUBLISH_URL=http://my_project.com/hub
MERCURE_JWT_SECRET=valid_generated_JWT_token
```

MERCURE_JWT_SECRET is a valid JWT token generated with JWT_KEY from Docker configuration (MySecret) with payload:

```
{
    "mercure": {
        "publish": []
    }
}
```

When I try a simple example like this:

```
public function getCountUnreadMessagesAction(Publisher $publisher)
{
     // some API logic

    $update = new Update(
        'http://my_project.com/api/v1/messages/count-unread',
        json_encode(['count' => $count])
    );

    // The Publisher service is an invokable object
    $publisher($update);

    // return 200
    return $this->ok((int)$count);
}
```

I'm getting a error "Couldn't connect to server for "http://my_project.com/hub"

Tried to add port 9090 or 80 on MERCURE_PUBLISH_URL but the same error appears. I have restarted Docker each time when changed .env file.

How to properly set URL to Mercure hub with Docker configuration?

**EDIT:**

My JS code which is outside Docker:

```
  <script type="application/javascript">
      const es = new EventSource('http://my_project.com:9090/hub?topic=' + encodeURIComponent('http://my_project.com/api/v1/messages/count-unread'));
      es.onmessage = e => {
          // Will be called every time an update is published by the server
          console.log(JSON.parse(e.data));
      }
  </script>
```

I don't have a problem with CORS after set - CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS=* in Docker. I don't use JWT in JS for authentication.

Comment: Does the java code using JWT token is in the same container as `symfony/mercure`

Comment: Thank you for your comment @mchawre . I updated question with JS part. I dont use JWT in JS part.

Answer (score 6):

I finally figured out.

It should be docker container name:

```
MERCURE_PUBLISH_URL=http://mercure/hub
```